# Change class depending on window and page size.

Tags: javascript, css

I have a DIV at the bottom of my page.

Basically if the page height is smaller than the window I want it's class to be "firstclass".

And if the page height is taller than the window I want it's class to be "secondclass".

Can anyone help me out? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `document.body.offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` will give you width and height of the current window.

Compare that to the height of your page.

or jquery `height()` and `width()` on the window
from jquery docs:

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare:

```
window.innerHeight
```

and

```
document.body.offsetHeight
```